# React Router V6 Redirection to 404 page

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm building a React app and I would like to know how I can redirect to a 404 page if when in the onMount method of the component. I don't find any data coming from the api

I have already build the 404 page and route

```
<Route path="*" element={<NotFoundView />} />
```

Code:

```
  const getExercice = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await http.get(`/exercicePost/${id}`);
      if (response.status !== 400) {
        setExercice(response);
      }
    } catch {}
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (id !== undefined) {
      setTitle(id.replaceAll("-", " "));
      setTitleSplit(id.split("-"));
    }
    getExercice();
  }, [""]);

  if (exercice !== undefined) {
    return (
      <div className="main-container single-exercice">
        <div className="single-exercice-go-back grid grid-cols-3 ">
          <ButtonGoBack text="retour" link="../" />
        </div>
        <div className=" md:grid  md:grid-cols-3 gap-4">
          <div className="single-exercice-title">
            <span className="single-exercice-title-transparent">Exercice</span>
            {titlesplit.map((element: string, id: number) => (
              <span className="single-exercice-title-full" key={id}>
                {element}
              </span>
            ))}
          </div>

          <ImageWrapper imgUrl="d" alt="d" />
        </div>
        <div className="single-exercice-description">
          <PartFrame title="Description" />
          <p>{exercice.description}</p>
        </div>

        <div className="single-exercice-how-to">
          <PartFrame title={"Comment faire le " + title} />
          <TextList list={exercice.howToRealise} />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  } else {
    return <h1>Wrong name</h1>;
  }
};
```

I would like to instead of returning `<h1>Wrong name</h1>` redirect the user to the path "*" and not mount the page.

Comment: what do you mean by `data` is not coming ? by an error or how ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**solution 1 :**
**change  :**

```
else {
    return <h1>Wrong name</h1>;
  }
```

**to  :**

```
else {
    return <NotFoundView />;
  }
```

do not forget to import `import  NotFoundView  from "<path>/NotFoundView  ";`

**Solution 2 :**

use the `useNavigate` hook  in your case  :

```
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
function Test () {
  const navigate = useNavigate();  
  if (.......) {
    return ...........;
  } else {
    return navigate("*");
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you it was so simple I don't know why I didn't think of it

Comment: it happens if it didn't work the way you want think of another one